# Standalone Procedure Error in Cursor to a basic table

Tags: sql, oracle, logic, procedures

I'm trying to use a standalone external procedure to be ran from within a cursor, take a variable and throw it back to the procedure, where the procedure will insert the values into another table. Getting errors.

**PROCEDURE:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test
(p_inn   newtable.totalhours%TYPE) AS

BEGIN
p_inn := p_inn - p_inn + 1;
INSERT INTO proceduretest (value)
VALUES (p_inn);
END proc_test;
/
```

**The code with cursors**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
        v_idno  paydata1.idno%TYPE;
        v_name  paydata1.name%TYPE;
        v_hrs   paytran1.hourswk%TYPE;
        v_hrsT  paytran1.hourswk%TYPE;
        v_code  paydata1.jobcode%TYPE;
        v_payh  paydata1.payhr%TYPE;
        v_sal   paydata1.salary%TYPE;
        v_OT    NUMBER(6,2);
        CURSOR payday IS
        SELECT idno, name FROM paydata1
        ORDER BY idno;
        CURSOR paytray IS
        SELECT hourswk FROM paytran1
        WHERE v_idno = idno
        ORDER BY idno;
        CURSOR total IS
        SELECT idno, name, jobcode, salary, payhr
        FROM paydata1
        WHERE v_idno = idno;
        BEGIN
        OPEN payday;
        LOOP
          FETCH payday INTO v_idno, v_name;
          EXIT WHEN payday%NOTFOUND;
          IF paytray%ISOPEN THEN
          CLOSE paytray;
          END IF;
           OPEN paytray;
           v_hrsT := 0;
           LOOP
            FETCH paytray INTO v_hrs;
            EXIT WHEN paytray%NOTFOUND;
            v_hrsT := v_hrsT + v_hrs;
           END LOOP;
            OPEN total;
             FETCH total INTO v_idno, v_name, v_code, v_sal, v_payh;
             WHILE total%FOUND LOOP
              IF v_code = 'S' THEN
               v_sal := v_sal / 52;
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' - Total hours worked is: ' ||  v_hrsT);
                proc_test (v_hrsT); <------------------

              ELSE
                IF v_hrsT > 40 THEN
                 v_OT := v_hrsT - 40;
                 v_OT := v_OT * (v_payh * 1.5);
                 v_OT := v_OT + (40 * v_payh);
                 v_sal := v_OT;
                ELSE
                 v_sal := v_hrsT * v_payh;
                END IF;



                 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_name || ' - Total hours worked is: ' || v_hrsT);
proc_test (v_hrsT); <---------------
END IF;
              FETCH total INTO v_idno, v_name, v_code, v_sal, v_payh;
             END LOOP;
            CLOSE total;
           CLOSE paytray;
          END LOOP;
         CLOSE payday;
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

I apologize, some of the code got messy towards the end, but I've drawn arrows to where the procedure is called.

**ERRORS:**

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
5/1      PLS-00363: expression 'P_INN' cannot be used as an assignment
         target
```

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: Why do you have three cursors selecting from the same table nested insider each other?

Comment: For future reference this is not an external procedure. ExtProcs are something different. The correct term is standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters with undefined direction default to IN. We cannot assign (change) the value of an IN a parameter. You have not defined the direction of P_INN so it's IN by default, therefore you cannot do this

```
p_inn := p_inn - p_inn + 1;
```

That's what the error message is telling you.

If you don't need the manipulated value for anything other than inserting it just do that....

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test
    (p_inn   newtable.totalhours%TYPE) AS    
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO proceduretest (value)
    VALUES (p_inn - p_inn + 1);
END proc_test;
/
```

Otherwise use a local variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test
    (p_inn IN  newtable.totalhours%TYPE) 
AS    
    l_inn  newtable.totalhours%TYPE;
BEGIN
    l_inn := p_inn - p_inn + 1;
    INSERT INTO proceduretest (value)
    VALUES (l_inn);
END proc_test;
/
```

Comment: Thank you man, needed a good breakdown to understand this a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure expects two parameters but you call it with one.

EDIT:After your change, you use the parameter as if it was a variable. This is only allowed for OUT parameters. Anyway, your calculation makes little sense.

To do it, change your code like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_test (p_inn IN OUT newtable.totalhours%TYPE) AS
```

Comment: Even with just one I get the error. Changed the procedure in the post to match the one I'm using now.